# IdentityServer4 - Angular how to change the default Login page to Angular component

Tags: angular, identityserver4

How can I change the Login.cs.html page from IdentityServer4 to Angular component?

What should I do exactly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path to the login page via the [UserInteraction settings](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html?highlight=UserInteraction#userinteraction). Read more about IDS4 login flow [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html?highlight=UserInteraction#login-workflow).

For example if you have the angular app hosted on `http://localhost:3000` settings looks like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(
    options =>
    {
        options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "http://localhost:3000/login";
        options.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "http://localhost:3000/error";
        options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "http://localhost:3000/logout";
    })
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetTestUsers());
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@piotrkarpaa/using-spa-react-angular-ui-with-identity-server-4-dc1f57e90b2c) is a post with all details.

Comment: finally I used the scaffolded items added scaffolded items something like that u can there generate the pages and do any changes u need

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio